# When to use palets over color definitions in ConTeXt?

Tags: color, context

In the [Coloring ConTeXt manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/colors-mkiv.pdf), there is a small section about color palets. When looking at it one can reads

> Color palets are handy when you want to use a set of (named) colors but also want to switch efficiently between different definitions.

What are the practical use cases where color palets (`\definepalet`) should be preferred to color definitions (`\definecolor`)?

I am asking that question because even in ConTeXt source code, many "colorschemes" are defined as color definitions : [crayola](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-crayola.mkiv), [rgb](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-rgb.mkiv), [solarized](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-solarized.mkiv), [sgv](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-svg.mkiv), and more.

Comment: See [t-visualcounter](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) for an example.